# In Jenkins, how do I pass a web request body as a parameter to a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

So in my Jenkins pipeline (using the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin), I am trying to take the POST request JSON body and pass it into a Powershell script as an Argument. The body variable in the Jenkins pipeline is accessible via `echo body` which is weird because there is no variable delimiter in front of it - so i am unsure of how to pass it into the script.

The commented line is the line I'm trying to execute. Any leads are appreciated. Thanks!

```
node {
    echo body
    //powershell 'C:/Users/Ameera.Khan/Desktop/success_echo.ps1 -ArgumentList body'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{

echo body           // this `echo` is Jenkins step and Jenkins knows the var 
                    // named `body`, so it gets printed

bat 'echo body'     // this will print the string "body"

bat 'echo $body'    // this will print the content of (undefined) bat variable
                    // named `body`, so empty string

bat "echo ${body}"  // this will expand Groovy variable named `body` 
                    // and invoke `echo` on it
}
```

So in your case you might want

```
powershell "C:/Users/Ameera.Khan/Desktop/success_echo.ps1 -ArgumentList ${body}"
```

Comment: it needed single quotes to be read as a string, but yes! that did it. `'${body}'`